# Average case analysis resources to practice

Tags: algorithm, average

I am trying to understand analyzing the average case runtime of algorithms however, I am struggling to find a book or a website which lets me practice with some problem sets. I have tried looking into the textbook Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen and colleagues as well as Data Structures and algorithms by Narasimha Karumanchi but to no avail.  I would appreciate if someone recommends me some resources.

Comment: Various collections of problems exist. 
 For example https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms can let you practice writing algorithms for simple problems.  Or you can take courses like https://www.coursera.org/specializations/algorithms or https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-algorithms--cs215.

Comment: @btilly I don't think that will help much. He's trying to learn more about analysing the average case of an algorithm's time complexity.

Comment: I really appreciate the links given but @0x499602D2 is right, I need some problem sets related to average case analysis. Like here's an algorithm, find the average case of it for multiple testable algorithms.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The courses should help with that.